# Testing IE on Mac using Selenium Grid?

Tags: macos, internet-explorer, selenium

Is there a way to do this? I am having issues setting up the company's VM, and was wondering if there is an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can afford you can go for Cloud based cross browser testing services like [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/) or [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/).Both were easy to configure and works the same way grid works.All you have to do is give the remoteurl.You can try with trial license and see if it suits your need

You can see comparitive study of these and others [here](http://www.slant.co/topics/1511/compare/~browserstack_vs_sauce-labs_vs_testingbot)

Answer (score 0):

It's Feb 8, 2017 and I'm using BrowserStack to do Selemium Webdriver testing using mocha/node, W7/8.1/10, and IE11 and there are several issues with the platform and ie webdriver (2.3, per their site), e.g. input fields are not in view by default, wrong chars are sent to input fields, etc. It is also slow. I might start looking into running grid if we cannot get better use and value out of $80/month charge.